# Mix regular shared_ptr with a singleton shared_ptr/weak_ptr that should not be reference counted

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

An application I am working on has lots of classes of a common base class. The various objects are handled with `shared_ptr`. In some cases I have some global singleton objects that are used in the same system, i.e. sent to the same functions as the non-singleton objects. Since these also have to be wrapped in `shared_ptr` they get the ref-count increased and decreased unnecessarily since they can never go out of scope. These should rather be using `weak_ptr`.

Is there a way of mixing regular `shared_ptr` with a compatible type that does not do reference counting, (i.e. like a weak_ptr) to make singletons more efficient.

Example:

```cpp
// The singleton doesn't need reference counting, but has to be a shared_ptr
// to be used in the same function call.
static const std::shared_ptr<Something> singleton = std::make_shared<Something>(2);

void some_function(const std::shared_ptr<const Something> &a)
{

}

void main_function()
{
    auto object = std::make_shared<Something>(45);

    some_function(singleton);
    some_function(object)
}
```

Comment: At the cost of a little boilerplate, why not add a function that takes a raw pointer?  Your singletons can call that, as can the function that takes a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: If the function doesn't take part in any sharing ownership, it should take a pointer, not a reference to `shared_ptr`.

Comment: If you're passing the shared_ptr by reference, I don't think it increases reference counts. You have to pass by value -- forcing a copy to be created -- I think. But I'm not sure how to verify what I'm saying.

Comment: @JosephLarson: You’re right, and you have to be: taking a reference to a thing is not an observable event.

Comment: I tested and the reference count is increased when sent as reference as above. I also cannot change to use raw pointers since I want the function to take ownership it is just that it isn't needed for the singletons since they will never go out of scope.

Comment: The reference count increases because the object you are passing is of different type (`std::shared_ptr<Something>`) than the object the function accepts (`std::shared_ptr<const Something>`), so the compiler has no choice but to create a temporary. Would it not be possible to use the same type throughout?